# Assignvalue to field variable via Method call

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to assign a value to a field variable, so that the value should be assigned to variable in the beginning, as that variable is needed in many methods,  and i dont want to call  method again and again  in every method.

e.g

```
class MyClass  
{
    private string conn = "crms";
    private string connectionString = myMethod(conn);

    public string myMethod(string str)
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

but it gives me error, any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass  
{
    private string _conn = "crms";
    private string _connectionString = myMethod(conn);

    // Constructor
    public MyClass()
    {
        connectionString = whatever _conn
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
```

And the private variables will be set

Comment: It will not work, thats what I want to know, how to make this work >> `private string _connectionString = myMethod(conn);` I cannot call a method, it doesn't even appear for the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use @Prescott answer or you can modify it a little bit!

something like this:

```
private string _conn = "crms";
    private string _connectionString = myMethod(conn);

    // Constructor
    public MyClass(string connection)
    {
        connectionString = whatever _conn
    }
```

and you can use it like that:

```
var myClass = new MyClass("My Connection String");
```

if you're asking how to set a private field of a class using a method you can try this:

```
public string UpdateField(string conn)
{
    _conn = conn;
    return _conn;
}
```

this method will update your private field .. and you can delete the constructor if you don't need it.

Comment: It will not work, thats what I want to know, how to make this work >> `private string _connectionString = myMethod(conn);`   I cannot call a method, it doesn't even appear for the field.

Comment: do you want to set it inside this class or outside?!